# Problems connecting to Google IoT core via MQTT in C

Tags: c, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

I've set up the sample program from here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/mqtt-ciotc

When I try to run the example, the only error message that I get is:
'Failed to connect, return code 1'

I then moved on and tried the NodeJs version https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/mqtt_example

Using the same roots.pem, private and public keys, the NodeJs example works perfectly. I can view the incoming messages on Google Console.

Is there any tools available to help me debug what the issue is with the C example? Or any suggestions on what the problem could be?

Thanks,
A

Comment: Did you change in the example code in C : `.clientid = "projects/{your-project-id}/locations/{your-region-id}/registries/{your-registry-id}/devices/{your-device-id}",` and others options where you have to enter informations specifics to you?

Comment: Yes, I've set all of that. And the clientid on the C code matches up with exactly what's on the Java side.

Comment: I have just read somewhere that by default, the MQTT protocol can default to 3.1 which is not supported by Google, so I've set this in the C code: conn_opts.MQTTVersion = MQTTVERSION_3_1_1 and now I get a return code of 4, which is "Connection refused – bad username or password"

Comment: Maybe try printing the JWT and testing it on jwt.io

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of reasons to why this could be happening, including unsupported versions. The [Documentation for Cloud IoT](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/troubleshooting) provides some steps that you should verify first, but since you connected from the NodeJS code, we can discard some suggestions. What you could do to check errors is to use gcloud:

```
gcloud iot devices describe DEVICE_ID --project=PROJECT_ID --region=REGION --registry=REGISTRY_ID
```

The devices describe command may show additional error messages that can be used to help debug, including to verify that your device's credentials are not expired. Although some errors may not show up, my impression is that bad username or password errors would appear.